# Не так отображается формат даты в php

Tags: php

Для публикаций новостей нашел 1 плагин. Решил отредактировать  код и столкнулся с такой проблемой.

На сайте опубликовано 4 новости с такой датой - 15.12.2018.

В массиве я взял именно месяц и заменил цифры на текст.

Теперь у каждой  новости дата должна быть такой `15 дек 2018`, но у меня на сайте почему то только у одного поменялась дата, а у остальных не поменялась

```
if($blogdataon == 1) {
  //Вкл/Выкл. отображение даты создания материала
  $originalDate = $item->publish_up; 
  $newDate = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($originalDate));  
  $_monthsList = array(".01." => "янв", ".02." => "фев", 
    ".03." => "мар", ".04." => "апр", ".05." => "мая", ".06." => "июн", 
    ".07." => "июл", ".08." => "авг", ".09." => "сен",
    ".10." => "окт", ".11." => "ноя", ".12." => "дек"); 
  $_mD = date(".m."); 
  $newDate = str_replace($_mD, ' <span class="newsdata">'.$_monthsList[$_mD].' </span>', $newDate);
  echo '<div class="bloglatestnews6">'.$newDate.'</div>';
}
?>
```

Как сделать, чтобы у всех новостей отображался месяц текстом, т.е. `15 дек 2018` ?

Comment: $_mD = date(".m.", $originalDate);

Comment: Я правильно понимаю у вас joomla? Просто насколько помню там можно создать файл русификации и там указать месяца, и она сама поставит их названия и формат тоже настраивается.

Comment: нет теперь ваще не работает.

Comment: да я joomla использую

Comment: и я плагин(называется mod_bloglatestnews) использую что бы новостей опубликовать на главном странице, и в коде этого плагина создается локальная переменная и к нему присвоили новую дату

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  $newDate = new DateTime('01.12.1974'); 

  $_monthsList = [
      '01' => 'янв',
      '02' => 'фев',
      '03' => 'март',
      '04' => 'апр',
      '05' => 'май',
      '06' => 'июн',
      '07' => 'июл',
      '08' => 'авг',
      '09' => 'сен',
      '10' => 'окт',
      '11' => 'ноя',
      '12' => 'дек'
  ]; 
  $template = sprintf(
      "<div class=\"bloglatestnews6\">%s <span class=\"newsdata\">%s</span>%s</div>",
      $newDate->format('d'),
      $_monthsList[$newDate->format('m')],
      $newDate->format('Y')
  );
  echo $template;
```